# How to refresh radio button in list user (table)

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, checkbox, radio-button

When I click the radio button, the popup display detail user A correct, but when I click in radio of line 2 (userB), the popup display details of user A (also details userA and no detail for userB). How do I resolve this issue to refresh the radio button

My HTML:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="nm in listeOfUsers |filter:searchFish ">
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="checked" ng-checked="nm.checked" ng-change="changeVal()"
            value="{{nm.Id}}"
            ng-model="nm.checked" ng-click="resetAll(nm)"/>
        </td>

        <td> 
            {{nm.nom}} 
        </td>

        <td> 
            {{nm.prenom}} 
        </td>

        <td> 
            {{nm.email}} 
        </td>

        <td> 
            {{nm.designation}} 
        </td>

        <td> 
            {{nm.Site}} 
        </td>

        <td>
            <center>
                <span ng-if=" nm.IsActive == true " class="label label-warning">Activé</span>
            </center>
            <center>
                <span ng-if="nm.IsActive == false " class="label label-danger">Non Activé</span>
            </center>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

My Javascript:

```
function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
    console.log(item.checked);
    console.log(item);
    User.UserById
    ({id:item.Id},
    function (res){
        $scope.mm = res;
        console.log($scope.mm);
        $scope.registration.Password=$scope.mm.password;
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        $state.go($state.current, $stateParams, {
            reload: true,
            inherit: false,
            notify: true
        });
   };

  $scope.registration.Email=item.email;

  $scope.registration.Users_Role=item.designation;
  $scope.registration.Site=item.site;
  $scope.registration.nom=item.nom;
  $scope.registration.Prenom=item.prenom;
}
]
};
  $uibModal.open(dialogOpts);
}
```

Comment: This entirely depends on the code which you haven't shown us. Therefor no one can accurately answer this question. Please edit the question to include the JS and HTML.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, ok now it's ok